# Using EF6 Store Functions for Entity Framework code-first, can I return a custom type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an entity class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

using the [EF6 Store Functions for Entity Framework code-first](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/) by Moozzyk, I see example code that maps a function to an entity type.

However, when using a type that isn't already mapped as an entity, I receive an exception saying the type is not a valid entity type.

Example:

```
[DbFunction("MyContext", "GetValueSum")]
public IQueryable<SomeClassSummary> GetValueSum()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext
            .CreateQuery<SomeClassSummary>(string.Format("[{0}].{1}", GetType().Name,
            "[GetValueSum]()"));
}
```

How can I output the call of that function to a specific type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type to be returned must have columns named the same as the function.  For example, if the function returns columns:

```
Name nvarchar
Sum  int
```

then SomeClassSummary should be:

```
public class SomeClassSummary {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the context, add the class as a complex type:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<SomeClassSummary>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention<MyContext>("dbo"));
}
```

Comment: ComplexType was the bit I was missing.  The CodeFirstStoreFunction documentation is a little light around this, probably could do with a few examples in the vast documentation.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was tripping over trying to add it as an Entity.  Adding it as a ComplexType solved it.