# Possible ways to call database function in EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Consider I have some code first model in my app and some snippet:

```
var myQueryable = (IQueryable<MyEntity>dbContext.MyEntitySet;
var myFilteredQueryable = externalService.Filter(myQueryable);
```

Now, I need to call stored function from database in order to add additional criteria, sth like this:

```
WHERE MyFunc(MyCol) = 1;
```

I know, there is no posibility to create own function with `EdmFunciton` to use it like this:

```
myFilteredQueryable = myFilteredQueryable.Where(myEnt => MyFunctions.MyFunc(myEnty.MyCol);
```

It is available in Databse first / Model first.

I know I can run it directly:

```
var selectedIds = myFilteredQueryable.Select(m => m.Id).ToArray();
var filteredIds = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlQuery<int>("SELECT Id FROM MyEntity WHERE MyFunc(MyCol) = 1 AND ID in (" + string.Join(selectedIds, ",") + ")").ToArray();

myFilteredQueryable = myFilteredQueryable.Where(myEnt => filteredIds.Contains(myEnt.Id));
```

Performance of this solution is not good one.. What are other ways to filter by queryable by function? I am obligated to use Code First and cannot modyify external service.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29539227/1236044 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29594251/1236044 may be of some help

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.