# How can I convert string into int without enumerating a query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Probably I'm blind, but I can't find how to convert string to int. I wrote

```
query.OrderByDescending(a => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(
    a.Index.Substring(a.Index.Length - 4, 4)) == 1 ?
    Convert.ToInt32(a.Index.Substring(a.Index.Length - 4, 4)) :
    0);
```

But, as I suspected,  it returns an error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   ToInt32(System.String)'

Moreover *SqlFunctions* don't have a member *Convert*. Is any way to achieve this without enumerating the query?

EDIT:
`int.Parse` throws

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Parse(System.String)

Comment: Does `int.Parse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` work?

Comment: It might work by simply casting to int.

Comment: int.Parse was first thing to try, its throw the same error

Comment: @JonSkeet What difference that makes? I'm missing that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: It was possible that LINQ to Entities knew about `int.Parse` but not about `Convert.ToInt32`. That appears not to be the case, but it was at least possible.

Comment: @Andrew: You can't cast from `string` to `int`.

Comment: Hmm. I've seen other posts that suggest `Convert.ToInt32` *should* work in EF. Interesting.

Comment: This issue is a bit frustrating.  I ran into it just yesterday afternoon.  One thing that you have to keep in mind is that EF has to be able to generate the SQL regardless of the provider.  For example, the generated SQL may be different between SQL Server and MySQL.  It has to be generic enough that it can handle all situations.

Comment: Yes, i found it too, that's why i post Convert.ToInt32 instead int.Parse and earned -2 :)

Comment: Can you make sort on client (e.g. call `ToArray` for `query`)? Or it works slow for your case?

Comment: I have many, many records, after sorting I get only 1 page of entities , so it have to be on sql side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long shot as I have not tried it myself (I read about it a few weeks ago).

If the SqlFunctions class does not provide a function that you need, you can create a custom function on the SQL Server side and then create a class on the .NET side similar to the SqlFunctions class to call the custom function.  There is an attribute that you have to decorate the .NET class with.

Perhaps something like this would work?

You can read more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456847(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmfunction(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: this sounds nice, but like a workaround quite common problem. If no one knows any shorter way that will be the answer.

Comment: @MarcinJ Note that if you are using code first instead of edm files, you have to do like http://stackoverflow.com/a/23658354/613130

Answer (score 0):

`int a=int.Parse(string);`

is the way you can convert a string into int in c#

Answer (score 0):

`int.TryParse(X.Number, out tmp) ? tmp : 0`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with `TryParse`? something like this:

```
int number;
query.OrderByDescending(a =>(
                        int.TryParse(a.Item1.Substring(1, 2), 
                                        out number) == true  ? number: 0));
```

I always use `TryParse` with lambda expressions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JNYRanger ok i wanted to comment his post but i realize that i don t have enough reputation. I thought it was one possible solution to his question.

I ll ve it in mind for next time.

Comment: Sorry, @JNRanger - I think its a reasonable attempt at an answer.