# Entity Framework Code First Function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an interesting problem with EF Code First and MSSQL user defined functions.
I write a database function that returns a scalar value and I want to map that function to my DbContext.

Based on information that I found I wrote this:

```
[DbFunction("AppDbContext", "GetNextDocumentNumber")]
public virtual int GetNextDocumentNumber()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
        .ObjectContext
        .ExecuteStoreCommand("GetNextDocumentNumber");
}
```

I also write a simple unit test to check if function returns correct values.
The problem is that this code above returns -1. When I execute function on SMSS I get correct result.

After searching on the different sites I have found a solution thatlooks like this:

```
public virtual int GetNextDocumentNumber()
{
    return this.Database
         .SqlQuery<int>("select dbo.GetNextDocumentNumber()")
         .Single();
}
```

In this case i get the correct value.

I just want to know what is wrong with the previous code or what am I doing wrong. In both cases I get a value. But only in one case value is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008369/calling-db-function-with-entity-framework-6) may provide an answer to what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Calling function in LINQ expression solved my problem.