# Entity Framework 6 Code First Custom Functions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying something similar to this:

[How to use scalar-valued function with linq to entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481868/how-to-use-scalar-valued-function-with-linq-to-entity)

However I'm not using EDMX, but instead just DbContext and code first.

I've come across this:

https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/

But the usage isn't suitable. What I am trying to achieve is to be able to do this:

```
var locations = context.Locations.Where(e => Functions.LatLongDistanceCalc(e.Lat, e.Long, lat, long) >= 10)
```

Where it will call a scalar function (LatLongDistanceCalc) on SQL Server.

Is there any way to do this without using EDMX? I know that you can construct a manual query but this wouldn't be prefereable because I want to bring back entities with lazy loading proxies etc as well as building up a more complex query.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should be able to use a scalar SQL function in your `Where` criterias with [CodeFirstStoreFunctions](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/)

Assuming you want to map SQL function [dbo].[LatLongDistanceCalc], and according to [the test suite](https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CodeFirstStoreFunctionsSamples/ScalarFunctionSample.cs):

```
public class MyDataContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       //...

       modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention("dbo", this.GetType()));
    }

    // "CodeFirstDatabaseSchema" is a convention mandatory schema name
    // "LatLongDistanceCalc" is the name of your function

    [DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "LatLongDistanceCalc")]
    public static int LatLongDistanceCalc(int fromLat, int fromLong,
                                                       int toLat, int toLong)
    {
       // no need to provide an implementation
       throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

usage would then be:

```
context.Locations
       .Where(e => MyDataContext.LatLongDistanceCalc(e.Lat, e.Long, lat, long) >= 10)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I didn't get this earlier but this works 100%. Thanks you!

Comment: I would like to add that this works if you are within the select/context.
If you are outside of it - it won't work.

Comment: I've been trying to use it with a Max function I've created, no input parameters and so far no success. I always get the NotSupportedException.

Comment: @yopez83 you should post a question with details on your problem so that someone can help you

Comment: I have a question, this answer don't support this situation.  sql like this: 
 select  id, dbo.fnDecrypt(seller, 'key123') as seller from table where dbo.fnDecrypt(seller, 'key123') like '%seller name%',  and the first parameter of fnDecrypt is varbinary(max), it's result using sql server EncryptByPassPhrase algorithm，seller property of class is string.