# Manipulating Entity Framework sql query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, spatial-query

Is there any way to manipulate the entity framework query.

I have a class that has a geometry column.

```
public class Geom
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

Database context is getting data from database.

```
        using (var database = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var items= database.Geoms;
        }
```

This sends database an sql query like: `"select id,name,geometry from geoms"`

I want to change the query before send database like this:

```
 "select id,name,ST_AsText(geometry) from geoms"
```

is this possible?

Because I am using postgresql database so can not use DbGeometry.

Comment: This might be overkill, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/33442340/242520