# Entity Framework Core Custom Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to implement something like this for Entity Framework Core 5?
[Code first Entity Framework 6.1 Custom Aggregate Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437455/code-first-entity-framework-6-1-custom-aggregate-function)

Comment: Short answer no. But you can use extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) which can handle custom aggregates.